# Route pattern error: cannot reference variable name more than once

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have the following route in web.php

```
Route::resource("api/companies/{kind}", "api\Companies", ['only' => ['index', 'create', 'store', 'show']] );
```

Having that route will give me an error:

```
Route pattern "/api/companies/{kind}/{{kind}}" cannot reference variable name "kind" more than once.
```

However, if I remove the 'show' option from the route, it works:

```
Route::resource("api/companies/{kind}", "api\Companies", ['only' => ['index', 'create', 'store']] );
```

Can't see what's wrong with my route, and what's the relationship with the 'show' option.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your wildcard,

```
Route::resource("api/companies", "api\Companies", ['only' => ['index', 'create', 'store', 'show']] );
```

Refer to this documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes

Home this help :)

Comment: I need that {kind} that's passed to my controller by Laravel.

Comment: it automatically give a wildcard when using resource routing , to do so , you can call $companies in your controller.

Comment: Excuse me but it's not clear what you mean. What do you mean "call $companies"

Comment: when using resource routing, it automatically gives an wildcard which is, you do not need to give an wildcard {kind}, if you want to use wildcard {kind} you can use , Route::resource("api/companies/kind", "api\Companies")..

Answer (score -1):

```
Route pattern "/api/companies/{type}/{kind}" cannot reference variable name "kind" more than once.
```

You cannot use the variable twice in routes. change it something else.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. I don't have it twice in my route...?